# Solidity unit type holding an array?

Tags: solidity

I am working through the solidity course cryptozombies and heres something im not understanding

```
struct Zombie {
  string name;
  uint dna;
  uint32 level;
  uint32 readyTime;
  uint16 winCount;
  uint16 lossCount;
}

Zombie[] public zombies;

mapping (uint => address) public zombieToOwner;
mapping (address => uint) ownerZombieCount;

function _createZombie(string memory _name, uint _dna) internal {
    uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna, 1, uint32(now + cooldownTime), 0, 0)) - 1;
    zombieToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
    ownerZombieCount[msg.sender]++;
    emit NewZombie(id, _name, _dna);
}
```

Based on my understanding "zombies" is an array containing a string and different type of integers. If you look in the _createzombie function "id" is set as an uint. How can something of type uint store all these values?

Answer (score 0):

> *Based on my understanding "zombies" is an array containing a string and different type of integers*

This is only partially correct. `zombies` is in fact an array. But each of its items is of type `Zombie`.

A struct ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#structs)) is kind of a "wrapper" type - it can contain multiple other datatypes on the inside, but from the outside it's seen as just one datatype (in this case **you created a new datatype called `Zombie`**).

You can see it for example in the `push()` function that accepts one new item of the array - type `Zombie` (wrapping the other variables).

```
zombies.push(
    Zombie(...) // pushes 1 item of type `Zombie` to the array
)
```